# how to insert text and images in database and retrieve in listview in android with values entered in edittext

Tags: android, image, sqlite, listview

I want to insert values from edittext and select image and then store it into the database and retrieve in listview. I successfully inserted the edittext values like name and password in listview bt dont know how to insert images and retrieve it with name and all stuff. plz give some sample code.

thanks in advance!

Comment: in which type you store image in database?

Comment: it is in the form of byte[]

Comment: it suggest you that store it in local server and retrive it using lazy adapter

Comment: will you plz give me any sample code???

Answer (score 0):

First create a custom list view follow the link given below 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/
and store data into DataBase use 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: saving images in sqlite is not advisable. Better you save images on external memory(sd_card) or save in the phone memory.

Comment: Actually in my main activity i have a listview which shows only the names and a addNew button which opens the edittext and image select activity. Now i dont know how to set that custom listview row to the main activity which show all the data entered by user in second activity.

Comment: @kumar- ya i knw that..i am saving the actual images on sd card only and giving the byte[] to database.bt dont knw how to do that with data eneterd by user.

Comment: @android Revolution- i dint get u.. which id to put in which button click??

Comment: Open new activity on button click .and put name into intent .That name used in new Activity ,for get data from sqlite database. search name from the database and display information in another activity.

Answer (score 0):

hi the below link shows how to upload image to the locally server [link](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/03/29/uploading-audio-video-or-image-files-from-android-to-server/) and save the url,name,password in database table

load all images form the URL  and data & display it efficiently using lazy list view refer this [lazylist link](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

Comment: But i want to get data entered by user.. like users enters the name and password and selects an image and then this data should be stored into database.

Answer (score 0):

Storing image in Sq lite using Blob is not an efficient way.
store the captured image in sdcard. and store the image uri to sqlite table.And retrieve from path. you can use timestamps for retrieving..

Comment: do not answer like comment,some sample code is asked in question so do give some useful link or code for the question to be accepted as answer